# Do Log makes mobile application speed slow?

Tags: android, performance

Do lots of logs used in android mobile application makes application speed slow?
Is there any affect on speed of application when using more logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs makes your app slow and there are only for debugging purposes! There are two things you can do. 1- manually remove all the logs for production version. 

2- Make a utility function to only log when your are in debug mode. Something like this

```
private void log(message){
    if(inDebugMode)
        Log.e('whatever', message);
}
```

Now instead of `Log.e` use `your custom log function` in your code.

A good way to detect debug mode is by checking app signature. You can use this unility function. https://github.com/alireza-1990/common-utils/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alirezaahmadi/commonutils/SignatureHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. You are doing the IO operation by writing to a log and IO operations are costly. It is always advisable to minimize and have meaningful logs. Also avoid v (verbose)/d(debug) logging in production.